# Эмулятор Samsung galaxy mega 6.3

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Есть приложение, мы протестировали его на всех доступных в генимоушине устройствах. Однако после отправки заказчику оказалось, что на  его Samsung galaxy mega 6.3 наблюдаются проблемы. Создали стандартный эмулятор с заданным разрешением, размером экрана и версией андроида - там все работает четко. Идти покупать реальный девайс - не вариант. Есть ли какие-то советы? Возможно какие-то дополнительные настройки гугловского эмулятора?
P.S. Проблемы наблюдаются с изображением

Comment: Вот бы рассказали, что за проблемы наблюдаются, какого вида, скриншотов приложили - был бы смысл.

Comment: К сожалению, не могу. Разработка коммерческая и распространять по условия контракта эту информацию я не имею права

Comment: Мне необходима просто информация как наиболее точно сэмулировать Samsung galaxy mega 6.3

Comment: раз разработка коммерческая - купите девайс.

Хотя вполне могли бы сказать, что там не так (например, картинка отображается кубиками, или с инвертированными цветами), но я подозреваю, что ваше NDA не позволяет сказать даже это.

Comment: Попробуйте [здесь][1] подобрать что-то максимально близкое. Но я бы, всё же, на вашем месте приобрёл физическое устройство.

  [1]: http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action

Comment: если проблема с изображением, есть вариант что  у хозяина подделка с низким dpi. потому и картинка имеет проблема. а что за проблема ? маленькая, большая, размазаная, какая? что за проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Я лично почти ненавижу Самсунг за их манеру перелопатить половину ОС перед заливкой на устройство. Обратите внимание на комментарий [@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf). Он предлагает хорошее решение. 
От себя предложу:

1. Купить один Самсунг среднего класса
       в компанию. Я надеюсь что я
       ошибаюсь, но скорее всего это далеко
       не последняя проблема с Самсунгами
       для вас. Если и дальше собираетесь
       разрабатывать под Андроид, я бы
       рекомендовал купить 1 Самсунг
       среднего класса, 1 Гуглофон (линейки
       Nexus, советую Nexus 4), 1 HTC тоже
       среднего сегмента (советую линейки
       Desire), и 1 Sony из сегмента
       Low-End.
2. Если ситуация критическая, и нету
       времени/денег на это все, скорее
       всего будет достаточно  найти
       кого-то из знакомых с Самсунгом
       среднего класса, и протестировать на
       нем. У Самсунгов похожее поведение
       на всех устройствах..

Comment: Да ладно все вендоры в той или иной мере лопатят на разную глубину ось. Все грешны и HTC тоже не ангел.

Comment: Самсунги есть, даже не один. На них все ок проблемы только на меге

Comment: @Barmaley как буд-то я говорю, что HTC хорошие...

Answer (score 1):

Обратитесь к профессиональным тестерам (есть такие компании), у них должны быть реальные девайсы на все случаи жизни. На просторах инета встречал несколько таких компаний, которые предлагали тестирование на нескольких сотнях устройств.

Comment: Спасибо, постараюсь поискать